# Setting a pointer to `nullptr` doesn't prevent double deletes?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a linked list implementation, in which I have a `LinkedList` class which contains a member called `head_` which is a pointer to a `LinkedListNode`. The `LinkedListNode` obviously contains a member called `next_`, which I can use to step through the list.

I have a destructor `~LinkedList`, which starts at the `head_` and steps through the list `delete`-ing all the pointers to `LinkedListNode` as it goes:

```
~LinkedList() {
  LinkedListNode *thru = head_;
  while (thru != nullptr) {
    LinkedListNode* toDelete = thru;
    thru = thru->next;
    delete toDelete;
    toDelete = nullptr; // LINE *
  }
```

This all works fine. My question is about what happened when I thought I'd be safe and stick in a destructor for the LinkedListNode class like so:

```
~LinkedListNode() { 
    if (next_ != nullptr) // LINE **
        delete next_;
}
```

This is giving me a stack overflow error, which I'm guessing is because I'm trying to double `delete` the `next_` pointers, once from the `LinkedList` and once from the `LinkedListNode`.

**My question is:** shouldn't setting the `toDelete` pointer to `nullptr` in line (*), plus the `if()` check in line (**), prevent the double delete error?

Comment: `delete next_;` is safe if `next_` is a `nullptr`, no need to check for that condition.

Comment: You are expecting magic.  Setting `toDelete` to `nullptr` does not magically set any other pointers to null.  It certainly does not set `thru` or `thru->next` to be `nullptr` in your code, nor does it set the `next_` pointer of any `LinkdListNode` to `nullptr`,  but you're assuming it does.    Since `toDelete` ceases to exist immediately after setting it to `nullptr`, the assignment to `nullptr` achieves nothing useful.

Comment: Even if the code worked, using a recursive destructor for `LinkedListNode` is very bad, especially for large lists.  It is a stack overflow waiting to happen.  Recursive loops are not good for linked lists, always use iterative loops only.

Comment: What if you want to delete a node without deleting the whole list? Surely it is a bad idea to try and have a node delete other nodes .

Comment: `toDelete` is a local variable of the destructor, `toDelete = nullptr;` therefore has no effect and probably the compiler will remove it . Not clear why you think this line would affect the rest of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is the following:

```
~LinkedListNode() { 
    if (next_ != nullptr) // LINE **
        delete next_;
}
```

Imagine you had a linked list 5, 4 , 3, 2, 1 and you have your head to be 5, your next would be 4, 3, and so on. When you call the function, what you will do is delete 4, and everything else will stay in your system, there is no way for you to delete 3, 2, 1 and so on, you deleted the only thing pointing to them, you have no access to them anymore. Many people are suggesting a recursive solution, well honestly it wouldn't work if you do it in the destructor if you really wanted to you would need another function like so:

```
void deleteLinkedList(Node* head){
    if(head == nullptr)return;
    Node* temp = head->next;
    delete head;
    deleteLinkedList(temp);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to swap 2 lines -`head = ` and `delete head`. Btw it is not a good idea to use recursion here, especially that loop here will be very easy.

Comment: Whoops what I just wrote will have a memory leak....